# How can I combine dates and true_predictions to create one DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two variables I'm trying to combine into one single DataFrame using the following code:

```
dates = '2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01','2018-04-01','2018-05-01','2018-06-01','2018-07- 
01','2018-08-01','2018-09-01','2018-10-01','2018-11-01','2018-12-01','2019-01-01','2019-02-01','2019- 
03-01','2019-04-01','2019-05-01','2019-06-01','2019-07-01','2019-08-01','2019-09-01','2019-10- 
01','2019-11-01','2019-12-01'

true_predictions = pd.DataFrame(true_predictions) (same length as dates)
```

I'm using the code below to create the DataFrame but I'm getting all the true_predictions as one row, not multiple rows for each value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [dates],'Travel':[true_predictions]})
```

How can I combine dates and true_predictions to create one DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. First make the dates and predictions into arrays:

```
dates = ['2018-01-01','2018-02-01','2018-03-01','2018-04-01','2018-05-01']
pred = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Then combine them into a dataframe. Note, do not put brackets around the array names.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates,'Travel':pred})
```

Comment: labels = [0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates,'Travel':true_predictions}, index=labels)

I used the code above, but I'mgetting a new error: "Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional"

Comment: Where are your true_predictions? Can you write out the true_predictions with dummy data?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to flatten the numpy arrays.

```
true_predictions = true_predictions.flatten()
```